# Enviar eventos con SokcetIO y NodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, socket.io

Tengo una ruta **/index** en la cual tengo el script siguiente

```
socket.on('m',function(){ console.log('hola mundo') })
```

en la ruta **/dos** tengo

```
$('#btn-send').click(function(){
      socket.emit('hola')
}
```

ambos poseen el connect, y se conectan bien en casos independientes, lo que necesito es que cuando de click en el botón sen en la ruta **/dos**, se emita 'hola' al server y el mismo emita 'm' que en la ruta **/index** escribe **hola mundo** en la consola, el server esta así , ahorrare código a copiar:

```
io.on('connection',socket => {
   socket.on('hola',()=>{
        socket.emit('m')
   })    
}
```

lo que pasa es que cuando pulso el botón send, nunca llega el evento 'm' a la ruta **/index** y no realiza la operación

Comment: En el emitir no te falta los parámetros? `socket.emit("m",{m:'mensaje'})`

Comment: no, cuando emites un evento no necesariamente necesitas enviar datos

Comment: Podrias copiar el codigo del cliente y el servidor, para identificar mejor el problema?

Comment: ese código que esta ahí es el mismo que tengo